# Angular: How to resolve [$injector:unpr] error for $httpProvider and inject controller in jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am new to angular testing. Facing some issues while testing angular code using jasmine.

It will be highly appreciated if you read my question and try to solve my problem as i googled it but could not find any satisfactory solution

Here is my angular app

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'toggle-switch',
    'ngTagsInput', 'blockUI', 'ngBootbox', 'ui.select', 'ngSanitize', 'angular.filter']);

app.config(["$httpProvider", "blockUIConfig", function ($httpProvider, blockUIConfig) {
    'use strict';
    blockUIConfig.autoBlock = false;
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptorService');
}]);
```

And here is controller file:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', '$window', '$ngBootbox', '$modal', 'dataservice', 'user', 'message_kinds',
    function($scope, $filter, $http, $window, $bB, $modal, dataservice, user, message_kinds) {
       $scope.user = user;
       /controller logic/
}]);
```

I want to test this controller if $scope.user equals to user or not.Am using jasmine for testing. Here is spec file.

```
describe("myController", function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe("myController testing", function () {

    it("should update scope.user", function () {
      var user = {customer_id: 1};
      var my_controller = $controller('myController', { user: user });
      expect(my_controller.user).toEqual(user);
    });
  });

});
```

I have also included all dependency files like angular.js, angular-mocks.js etc in SpecRunner.html

Having three problems:

1. Facing `[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=interceptorServiceProvide` error on `app.config` block regarding `$httpProvider`
2. `ReferenceError: $controller is not defined` in spec.js at line

   var my_controller = $controller('myController', { user: user });
3. How can I test if `scope.user` is equals to `user` in expect block?

Comment: Do you have an `interceptorService`? Or should it exist in any of the modules you are using?

Comment: What do you do with $http in your controller? If you are just retrieving some data from an API with it, remove that service from your controller and inject your own service that retrieves those items. I am just trying to make your controller cleaner so it is easier to test without injecting all those dependencies..

Comment: also do not inject $scope into your controller, you should be using the controller as syntax.. This won't fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

1) Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907163/how-to-karma-test-config-where-httpprovider-is-used-in-a-service-layer), as regards $http/$httpBackend which might help you - you can adapt this to get the answers you're looking for

2) Have you declared $controller (and now $httpProvider) as a variable in the beginning of the describe() block?

3) You should have that already. Your code, at least as I can see, looks like it should work like you want it to.

Comment: You can't inject `$httpProvider` with `inject`. And you shouldn't, it is already available in `config`. The problem is `interceptorService`.

Comment: @estus yes ia agree. Actual problem is interceptorService.

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar There's no `interceptorService` defined. Load a module that has `interceptorService`.